# Save Page State in Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to Navigate back and forth between SignIn and ForgotPassword Page using Navigation.push().

But the Forgot Password Page Keep Losing its state (the countdown timer here).

1. Home Page for App. [Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMW3F.png)
2. When I enter email it shows a message and a counter (goes from 30 to 0). [Page State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anPZO.png)
3. I go back to SignIn page and come back the timer and message are gone. [State Gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf8dE.png)

How to save a state for Navigation.push() page?

Forgot.dart

```
class ForgotPassword extends StatefulWidget {
  const ForgotPassword({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ForgotPasswordState createState() => _ForgotPasswordState();
}

class _ForgotPasswordState extends State<ForgotPassword> {
  TextEditingController emailC = TextEditingController();
  final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  AuthMethods authMethods = AuthMethods();
  bool sent = false;
  Timer? _timer;
  int _start = 0;

  void startTimer() async {
    if (formkey.currentState!.validate() && _start == 0) {
      _start = 30;
      const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
      _timer = new Timer.periodic(
        oneSec,
        (Timer timer) {
          if (_start == 0) {
            setState(() {
              timer.cancel();
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _start--;
            });
          }
        },
      );
      await authMethods.resetPassword(emailC.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(... rest of code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       body: PageView( 
          controller: _pageController,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            FirstScreen(),
            SecondScreen(),
          ],
        ),
```

replace Navigator.push()/pop() with _pageController.goToPage(0 or 1)

Comment: @Flut oh sorry I thought your function is running on initState(). Everything in build() method runs every time when the page is poped in. So instead of pushing to a new screen and coming back, you can use pageview. I will edit my answer wait.